# Check if element is present in header, body or footer selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Taking the example of this site:

https://www.imglobal.com

The contact number is present in the body of the webiste
[image]
Certain sites have it on top, along with the menu tabs, and certain sites at the bottom footer.

I have developed the routine to locate the element and its position using

```
    element.location
    element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

and to scroll into the view of the element

```
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element)
```

Is there a way to directly interpret if the element is present in the header/body/footer of the webpage, with the help of the tags, with selenium or bs4 in python.?

**EDIT**

Header example:
https://www.moeck.com/

Footer example:
https://www.andrew-kelly.co.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just using `element.parent` and loop over until you find one of your targeted tag?

Like something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = """<html><header><div><span class="phone">123456789</span></div><body><div></div><footer><div></div></footer>"""
location = ['header','body','footer']
page = soup(html, 'html.parser')

element = page.find('span',{'class':'phone'})

while (element.parent):
    if element.parent.name in location:
        print("Phone is in " + element.parent.name)
        break
    else:
        element = element.parent
```

**EDIT:**

To check class name too:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = """<html><header class='test-class'><div><span class="phone">123456789</span></div><body><div></div><footer><div></div></footer>"""
location = ['header','body','footer']
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

element = soup.find('span',{'class':'phone'})

while (element.parent):
    if element.parent.name in location and 'test-class' in element.parent.get('class'):
        print("Phone is in " + element.parent.name)
        break
    else:
        element = element.parent
```

Comment: thanks for the suggest. Does parent.name look for the tag name or the class name? I guess we can use element.parent['class'] for the class name.

Comment: how can I get the class/id name of the parent?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan you can add a `get('class')` on the `element.parent`. Be careful, it will return a list. See my edit :-)

Comment: thanks for the edit @Maaz. I just realized that my routine to find the element is more generic with selenium. Thus, I converted your routine with selenium's **get_attribute()**. Is there a way to get the tag of the element using selenium, similar to **.name** using bs4?